# Investigating the subgroup structure of $SL_{3}(\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z})$

Tags: group-theory, computer-algebra-systems

I'm trying to investigate the subgroups of $SL_{3}(\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z})$ through the use of GAP. However, whenever I try using LatticeSubgroups or ConjugacyClassesSubgroups, I either get a message telling me i've ran out of RAM, or it says that no method is know. I assume this is because of $SL_{3}(\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z})$'s order( I believe 43008?) is there anyway of giving more memory to gap to allow it to do calculations for long(i have 16gb so i have enough to spare) and/or a way to get it to know a method for dealing with groups of this size

thanks in advance

Comment: It might be possible to complete this computation with more memory (according to Magma, there are 4953 conjugacy classes of subgroups), but for investigating large groups, simply asking for all of their subgroups is too crude, and doesn't help a lot even if you succeed. You need to refine your questions.

Comment: @DerekHolt I want to look for groups of order 168. (Namely, SL$_{3}(2)$) .Is there a nice way search for subgroups of specific order?

Comment: @xyz-x please see https://www.gap-system.org/Faq/faq.html#7.7

Comment: @AlexanderKonovalov Hi, did you continue your gnu-search-project ?

Comment: @Peter hi, not actively - never got round to upgrade the database. So it's dormant at the moment.

Comment: @AlexanderKonovalov Enzo Creti has an interesting prime-finding-project. Perhaps you join in the search ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `-o` option, e.g.

```
gap -o 4G
```

Comment: Sorry, but when i do this my computer doesn't use anymore than 2gb. Have i done something wrong?